# Python - adding string elements from a list into an array

Tags: python, numpy

Here's an example of what I want to do. I want to take b and add this to my array but in a particular format (again I just want to know the steps to do this, my code deals with strings):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(25, dtype= np.character).reshape(5,5)
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in b:

    a[1:4,1:4] = i

print a
```

Output:

```
[['' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '9' '9' '9' '']
 ['' '9' '9' '9' '']
 ['' '9' '9' '9' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '']]
```

But what I want is this:

```
[['' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '1' '2' '3' '']
 ['' '4' '5' '6' '']
 ['' '7' '8' '9' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '']]
```

Could anyone give me an idea on how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(25, dtype= np.character).reshape(5,5)
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
a[1:4,1:4] = b.reshape(3,3)
print(a)
```

yields

```
[['' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '1' '2' '3' '']
 ['' '4' '5' '6' '']
 ['' '7' '8' '9' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '']]
```